# Android Kotlin + Klaxon - Parsing a JSON root array

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, klaxon

I have a JSON asset with a root array:

```
[
  {
    "word": "word",
    "label": "label"
  },
  {
    "word": "word2",
    "label": "label2"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to parse it using Klaxon.

So far I have tried several methods:

```
val wordDict = Klaxon().parse<List<DictWord>>( activity.assets.open("dict.json") )

val wordDict = Klaxon().parse<Array<DictWord>>( activity.assets.open("dict.json") )

val wordDict = Klaxon().parse<JsonArray<DictWord>>( activity.assets.open("dict.json") )
```

Which either results in an empty list or an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.beust.klaxon.JsonArray cannot be
> cast to com.beust.klaxon.JsonObject

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer in Klaxon's GitHub issue board: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/issues/87

Array parsing is done via `parseArray()`, so the fix was:

```
val wordDict = Klaxon().parseArray<DictWord>( activity.assets.open("dict.json") )
```

It is worth mentioning that array parsing is only supported via the streaming API, not the object mapping API. So we are limited to either supplying an `InputStream` or a `String` as an argument.

Comment: Actually it worked for Object mapping too, it successfully mapped each element of the array to an object of the corresponding data class I've defined for it.

Comment: Seems to be a new feature. Do you have any doc supporting your new find?

Comment: I've just tried it like this `val WordDict = ArrayList(Klaxon().parseArray<DictWord>(jsonString))`, I had to pass the parsed data into an `ArrayList` because `parseArray` returns a `List` while I needed an `ArrayList`.